# geoXML3, how to load all KML files in a folder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geoxml3

I have the below code in javacript using geoXML3 which successfully loads/parses and displays the KML file shown.

```
    var geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({map: map, singleInfoWindow: true});
    geoXml.parse('/myapp/resources/kml/fileone.kml');
```

The `/myapp/resources/kml/` folder/uri however holds many KML files. How I can load/parse them all at once to display them all on the google map at once?

I can't simply name them all because they're going to be different for different installations of the application. Wildcard doesn't seem to work;

```
    var geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({map: map, singleInfoWindow: true});
    geoXml.parse('/myapp/resources/kml/*.kml');
```

Comment: See this similar question: [List files in a directory using only javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924935/list-files-in-a-directory-using-only-javascript)

Comment: Hmm yes I was aware of such similar questions, with the answer being "No/Can't". However it does seem the geoXML.parse call is able to do just this, but for one kml file. Just wanted to know if it possible to get all the kml files.

Comment: Only if you can provide a list.  geoxml3 is implemented in javascript, so can't do it without a provided list of files.  If you provide an array of filenames (specific, no wildcards), it will open and parse them.

Comment: Ok, if you want to put that as an answer I'll flick you the accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

geoxml3  can only open files if you can provide a list. geoxml3 is implemented in [javascript, so it can't access the filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924935/list-files-in-a-directory-using-only-javascript). If you provide an array of filenames (specific, no wildcards), it will open and parse them.