# Download file from ftp with javascript in webpage

Tags: javascript, firefox, ftp, xmlhttprequest, html

I want to get list of files from ftp server and show to user to select some file and then download it.

I don't want to use server side code because the ftp server is not access with server.(it is in local of client side)

I search about it and I found `window.open` or `iframe` that only show ftp files in another window. but i want to manage the selection files with JavaScript.

also I find [this](http://I%20don't%20want%20to%20use%20server%20side%20code%20because%20the%20ftp%20server%20is%20not%20access%20with%20server.(it%20is%20in%20local%20of%20client%20side)) but it work only in IE and i want to work with Firefox and chrome.

so how can i access ftp with JavaScript code?

**Edit:**

Firefox says XMLHttpRequest  work with ftp in this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). but this don't work and get error `access to restricted URI denied`.

i search about this and find to add `netscape.security.Privilege.enablePrivilege( "UniversalXPConnect" )` but `netscape.security.Privilege` removed from Firefox after version 15.

so how can i send XMLHttpRequest  to ftp server from webpage with javaScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [List files in a directory using only javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924935/list-files-in-a-directory-using-only-javascript)